# Superfullcite not working with footmisc and hyperref

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, footnotes, footmisc

I would like to use the  [\superfullcite](https://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/) for formatting numbered citations as footnotes in biblatex, and then have the footnotes parallel using `\usepackage[para,bottom]{footmisc}`

This works well

[image]

until I include the `hyperref`-package which messes the kerning, and adds extra space between the body text and footnotes (extra space comes significant if one has more citations with hyperlinks).

[image]

Is there any workaround to include `hyperref`?

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[para,bottom,hang]{footmisc}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

% ------------------- superfullcite ----- %
\makeatletter

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker,sorting=none}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\notefullcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{notefullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{notefullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
       \usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}.}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\superfullcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{superfullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{superfullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
       \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
         \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}.}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother

% ------------------------ 

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}  

\lipsum[1]\superfullcite{kastenholz}
\lipsum[2]\superfullcite{companion,sigfridsson}
\lipsum[3]\superfullcite{augustine} \lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `hyperref` should be the last package to be loaded in the preamble. (There are a few documented exceptions like `cleverref` that must be loaded after `hyperref`, for more see [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/35864).)

Simply change the loading order to load `hyperref` later.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[para,bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% ------------------- superfullcite ----- %
\makeatletter

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker,sorting=none}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\notefullcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{notefullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{notefullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
       \usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}.}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\superfullcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{superfullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{superfullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
       \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
         \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}.}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother
% ------------------------

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\superfullcite{kastenholz}
\lipsum[2]\superfullcite{companion,sigfridsson}
\lipsum[3]\superfullcite{augustine} \lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

[image: Para footnotes with links]